# What is difference between broadband and baseband signal with respect to full duplex?

Tags: layer1, lan

We know that broadband signal is full-duplex, for example television cable line where all TV channel is used portion of bandwidth not full bandwidth. And modern baseband is also full duplex but all sending data used full bandwidth. My question is how baseband signal used full bandwidth where more than one sender sending data but in broadband signal using portion with respect to their sender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseband and broadband (in the technical sense) refer to the way data is encoded onto a medium. Baseband is "direct" (usually with just a line code allowing clock recovery) while broadband uses one or multiple carrier frequencies and appropriate modulations like QAM or (Q)PSK.

*Full duplex* means that a channel is used in both directions simultaneously - TV channels are generally simplex (from sender to TV set only) but with multiple channels in frequency-division multiplex (FDM).

On electrical cable, baseband signaling doesn't allow multiple simultaneous senders - or more precisely, not more than two on a point-to-point connection like with 1000BASE-T. This is *full duplex* in the tight sense, using hybrids and echo cancellation for separation. Other methods are *dual simplex* (one channel per direction, e.g. 100BASE-TX or fiber), or frequency-division duplex (FDD) on broadband (since there's only a single channel).

On fiber, *baseband signaling* refers to direct modulation of a specific wavelength of light. Many of those wavelengths can be used on a given fiber using wavelength-division multiplex (WDM). This is different from copper cabling since "baseband" on fiber actually means amplitude modulation of a carrier. For completeness, wavelength-division duplex (WDD) is also possible on fiber (e.g. 1000BASE-BX10, 10GBASE-BR10).

Comment: how baseband using full bandwidth it's not understanding?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "using full bandwidth". Baseband requires a certain bandwidth, depending on bitrate and encoding scheme, that the channel has to provide. Usually, the channel has much more (frequency-wise) bandwidth than is actually used, but it's not really practical (cost, latency, BER) to employ the full channel bandwidth (like VDSL tries for voice-grade cabling).

Comment: when more than one sender sends the data so how full bandwidth is used? Bandwidth isn't divided?

Comment: Baseband uses either dual simplex or echo cancellation for "full duplex". Broadband uses FDD = divided bandwidth.

Comment: if Baseband uses dual simplex or echo cancellation for "full duplex" then divided bandwidth is possible?

Comment: No, you don't need FDD with those variants.

Comment: one thing don't understand, when more than one sender sending data then how data using whole bandwidth? It should be divided bandwidth with respect to different sender data?

Comment: Dual simplex uses a dedicated channel for each direction. The full-duplex method used in 1000BASE-T onwards enables each sender to remove its own signal from the channel, so simultaneous transmission for P2P becomes possible.

Comment: simultaneous transmission means whole data of different sender treated as one data, then it uses whole bandwidth of the channel?

Comment: Not sure if get that - in 1000BASE-T each of the two senders uses the full bandwidth.

Comment: in that case bandwidth divided?I mean what will happen of two sender want to use full bandwidth?

Comment: *No, you don't need (use) FDD with those variants.*

Comment: if we don't need (use) FDD with those variants so how two senders use bandwidth at a time?

Comment: See *Dual simplex ...* above.

Comment: in dual simplex distinct sending and receiving channel for every sender ?

Comment: suppose 4 hosts connected to switch which has 4 different wires.And switch is connected to router by one wire. Now if 2 hosts want to transmit the at the same time then via switch then switch to router link treated as baseband or broadband?

Comment: Ethernet uses bandband signaling in general, with *very* few exceptions, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_physical_layer .